# MqSql - fetch rows which employee has maximum complaint severity level

Tags: mysql

I am dealing with a table `Employee Complaint` which has columns `EmployeeId` `ComplaintSeverity` and `ComplaintByUser`. `ComplaintSeverity` has four level 0,1,2, and 3.

So the table will look like this ,Example

```
ComplaintId|EmployeeId|ComplaintSeverity|usr_id
-----------------------------------
     1     |  1       |       0          |   3    
     2     |  2       |       1          |   4     
     3     |  3       |       0          |   5     
     4     |  1       |       2          |   4     
     5     |  4       |       1          |   5     
     6     |  2       |       2          |   2     
     7     |  2       |       2          |   4
```

Any user can complaint employee with any of these level

When client search with `severitylevel` as 0,
The row should fetch as

```
ComplaintId|EmployeeId|ComplaintSeverity
----------------------------
     3     | 3       |       0
```

for `severitylevel` as 1,

```
ComplaintId|EmployeeId|ComplaintSeverity
----------------------------
    5      |  4       |       1
```

for `severitylevel` as 2,

```
ComplaintId|EmployeeId|ComplaintSeverity
----------------------------
    4      |  1       |       2             
    6      |  2       |       2
```

`EmployeeId` 1 has been complained by 2 user with `severitylevel` 0,2 but his highest severity level is 2. so while searching for 0 level, 1 should not be displayed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why aren't the 4 levels 1 through 4? And what's your PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't provide the primary key in explanation. But i have the column in my table.

Comment: Great. What is it? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry : i had edited my question

Comment: I dont know who has downvoted. If you are not clear the question then ask me i will clear you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was edited after the previous answer was submitted. The following would therefore be more accurate.

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT employeeid
            , MAX(complaintseverity) severity 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY employeeid
     ) y 
    ON y.employeeid = x.employeeid 
   AND y.severity = x.complaintseverity 
 WHERE complaintseverity = 0 -- optional line
 ORDER 
    BY employeeid;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without join?

Comment: I am using hibernate query language. Will the above query suppotys hibernate?

Comment: I'm homeothermic, so can't comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT cs.`EmployeeId`, MAX(cs.`ComplaintSeverity`) severity 
    FROM ComplaintSeverity cs 
    GROUP BY cs.`EmployeeId`
) csdata
WHERE csdata.severity=1
```

Replace 1 with the severity level you want.

Comment: Unknown column 'csdata.severity' in 'where clause'

Comment: oops...really sorry i did mistake in query while editing.. Will try to change the severity=1 with all other levels

Comment: trying but getting exception

Comment: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 81 [SELECT x.employeeObj.employeeId FROM com.helperinfo.model.ComplaintModel x JOIN ( SELECT employeeObj.employeeId , MAX(compSeverityRef) severity FROM com.helperinfo.model.ComplaintModel GROUP BY employeeObj.employeeId ) y ON y.employeeObj.employeeId = x.employeeObj.employeeId AND y.severity = x.compSeverityRef WHERE compSeverityRef in (0) ORDER BY employeeObj.employeeId]

Comment: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 38 [SELECT x.employeeObj.employeeId FROM ( SELECT cs.employeeObj.employeeId, MAX(cs.compSeverityRef) severity FROM com.helperinfo.model.ComplaintModel cs GROUP BY cs.employeeObj.employeeId) csdata WHERE csdata.severityin (0)]

Comment: This is with yours query

Comment: i'm not sure about the hibernate as i do not code in it.

Comment: Thank for your help bro. I am fetching employee id using sql and again passing this employee id in hql... So two times it will hit database. this is working.    But i would like to write as single query . i will try and make it single..

Comment: you should modify your question or ask a new one with reference to this.